# myPlex with a VPN that supports port forwarding

Tags: networking, router, vpn, port-forwarding, plex

I'm using OS X, Viscosity and AirVPN. AirVPN supports port forwarding and I can successfully port forward with uTorrent and some other apps ... so in theory this should work:

1. Go to AirVPN, get a random port forwarded. For example, `18445`.
2. Go into Plex Media Server > Settings > Connect. Check Manually Specify
   Port, put in `18445`.
3. Click Update

Buuuut, this doesn't work. I get the `plex can't connect to you` message.

I've verified that this is the case using telnet. If I `telnet my.ip.addr 18445` I get nothing. If I telnet to the uTorrent port I get a response.

So what does Manually Specify Port mean anyway? It seems like plex is claiming that it will open an external socket on that port but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's how I successfully made MyPlex / PlexPass work with a VPN.**

**Prerequisites**:

- Mac OS X Mavericks/Yosemite (not yet verified on El Capitan)
- PIA/AirVPN/whatever (any VPN that supports port forwarding is fine)
- Any VPN client running on your mac

Steps:

1. **Forward the port on the VPN.**

Go to your VPN's web site to add a port forward.

I'm using AirVPN so I go to [airvpn.org/ports/](https://airvpn.org/ports/) and click the Add button. Don't fill in any of the fields. Let it assign a random port, and let it forward to the same local port.

Write down the randomly generated port number. You will need it later, whenever you see `VPN_PORT` in the instructions below, you will replace it with this number.

2. **Set up port redirection on your local machine**

Mavericks 10.9 and Yosemite 10.10 use `pf` (The OpenBSD Packet Filter) for port redirection.

Use the `Terminal` app to access the command line.

Create the file `/etc/pf.anchors/my.plex.vpn.forward` using your favourite editor, or nano:

```
sudo nano /etc/pf.anchors/my.plex.vpn.forward
```

Copy the following into the file:

```
# To allow access to Plex Media Server from outside the VPN AirVPN
# local ethernet for testing (en0)
rdr pass on en0 inet proto tcp from any to any port VPN_PORT -> 127.0.0.1 port 32400
# OpenVPN presumably is tun0
rdr pass on tun0 inet proto tcp from any to any port VPN_PORT -> 127.0.0.1 port 32400
```

Delete `VPN_PORT` on lines 3 and 5 and copy in the random port you wrote down above.

Save the file and exit nano.

To verify that your port forwarding file is correct:

```
sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.anchors/my.plex.vpn.forward
```

If you see `unknown port VPN_PORT` then you forgot to replace VPN_PORT in the file with your own randomly generated VPN port from step 1.

Create a `pf` config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/pf.plex.conf
```

Copy this into it:

```
rdr-anchor "my-plex"
load anchor "my-plex" from "/etc/pf.anchors/my.plex.vpn.forward"
```

Start `pf` (It doesn't run by default)

```
sudo pfctl -ef /etc/pf.plex.conf
```

3. **Configure Plex Server**

Go to Plex Media Server web interface > Settings > Server > Connect

Make sure you are signed in with your plexpass.

Check the box `Manually specify port` and enter `VPN_PORT` that you wrote down above. Click the button (Update/Retry/whatever).

You'll see "Connecting Server..."

After a few seconds you should see "Server is mapped to port [VPN_PORT]"

4. **Test it with your Mobile Phone**

First turn off WiFi. (Otherwise your phone might connect on the local network and that's not what we want.)

Log in

It should automatically connect now. If not, try Refresh, Sync, and or waiting a minute.

Once you can see it works you can turn WiFi back on.

---

Extra stuff:

- To make pf run automatically when you reboot your mac, see [OS X
  Server: How to enable the adaptive firewall](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT200259?viewlocale=en_US) (except change the
  conf file from pf.conf to pf.plex.conf)
- You can test from inside and outside your network using telnet, e.g. `telnet IP.ADDR.OF.PLEXMAC VPN_PORT` and if it connects your settings are correct.
- This wouldn't be necessary if Plex server were updated to listen on all network interfaces including the vpn interface.